# How to change the default certificate chain in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, ingress

I'm using AKS on Azure and Ingress with Let's Encrypt certificate (configured by https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip)

The certificate chain defaults to `DST Root CA X3` but I would like to change it to alternative `ISRG Root X1`

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/#cross-signing says

> Almost all server operators will choose to serve a chain including the intermediate certificate with Subject “Let’s Encrypt Authority X3” and Issuer “DST Root CA X3.”

Can you tell me, how can I change the default intermediate certificate to `Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 (Signed by ISRG Root X1)`?

I know `ISRG Root X1` should become default on September 29, 2020 (https://letsencrypt.org/2019/04/15/transitioning-to-isrg-root.html) so I can just wait (not optimal). But after that this can be useful for someone who needs to keep `DST Root CA X3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/), optional control of the intermediate certificate [isn't available yet](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1700).

That doesn't stop you from issuing your own certificate with certbot which [has added support to select the chain](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/8080) and [installing that on the ingress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls).

```
certbot ... --preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1"
```

Any unknown value for `preferred-chain` will give you the default chain.

Comment: Works great, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a spot late, but this is supported now.  You can configure your issuer like this:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    preferredChain: "ISRG Root X1"
```

See [this page](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/) for more